# Vertically align logo and personal details in moderncv

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, moderncv

I am writing a cover letter in `moderncv` and would like to vertically align the placement of a logo and the name field/personal details (the logo and name should be parallel/vertically aligned). However, my current code has the logo higher than the name/personal details.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}      
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}

\moderncvstyle{classic}   
\moderncvcolor{green} % Bullet point color                          

% Page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry} % Page margins

% Your Information, please revise
\name{Don}{Jones}
\address{123 Lane}{City, Zip}
\phone[mobile]{123-123-1234}                   
\email{email@uni.edu}

%--------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------%

% Insert Logo
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.60\textwidth]{signature_print.jpg}
\end{minipage}


\recipient{Dear Members of the Search Committee,}{}
\opening{\vspace*{-2em}}
\closing{Sincerely,}{\vspace*{-2em}}
\enclosure[Enclosures]{Curriculum Vitae, Writing Sample, Transcript}   
\makelettertitle

\justifying

My resume is enclosed, and will give you further insight into my skill set and experience. I would like to schedule an interview so I could express my desire to join XXX company and learn more about the position.

\vspace{0.5cm}

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to move the image into position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}      

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   

\moderncvstyle{classic}   
\moderncvcolor{green} % Bullet point color                          

% Page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry} % Page margins

% Your Information, please revise
\name{Don}{Jones}
\address{123 Lane}{City, Zip}
\phone[mobile]{123-123-1234}                   
\email{email@uni.edu}

\recipient{Dear Members of the Search Committee,}{}
\opening{\vspace*{-2em}}
\closing{Sincerely,}{\vspace*{-2em}}
\enclosure[Enclosures]{Curriculum Vitae, Writing Sample, Transcript}   

%--------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------%

\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-2.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth,height=3\baselineskip]{example-image}%
}%

\makelettertitle

My resume is enclosed, and will give you further insight into my skill set and experience. I would like to schedule an interview so I could express my desire to join XXX company and learn more about the position.

\vspace{0.5cm}

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Of course, if you're only printing a letter, there's no need for using [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv); you can just use the `article` class for that.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thanks so much. Makes of ton of sense and really easy to adjust - thanks!